# Calculate cumulative measure in MDX

Tags: mdx, mondrian, cumulative-sum

I need to define a CumulativeSales measure in a mondrian catalog definition. So far, I have this:

```
    <CalculatedMember name="CumulativeSales" dimension="Measures" >
        <Formula>IIF([Month.Year].CurrentMember.Level.Name = 'Month', Sum([Month.Year].CurrentMember.FirstSibling:[Month.Year].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Sales]), Sum([Month.Year].CurrentMember.Children, [Measures].[Sales]))</Formula>
        <CalculatedMemberProperty name="FORMAT_STRING" value="$ #,##0.00;$ #,##0.00;#"/>
    </CalculatedMember>
```

MDX snippet as follows:

```
IIF
(
  [Month.Year].CurrentMember.Level.Name = 'Month'
 ,Sum
  (
    [Month.Year].CurrentMember.FirstSibling : [Month.Year].CurrentMember
   ,[Measures].[Sales]
  )
 ,Sum
  (
    [Month.Year].CurrentMember.Children
   ,[Measures].[Sales]
  )
)
```

But sometimes it doesn't work well, particularly when showing cumulatives sales in months with no sales. For example, in this query:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[CumulativeSales]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Department].[All]} ON ROWS
FROM [Production]
WHERE 
  CrossJoin
  (
    {
      [Activity].[Services].[DP]
     ,[Activity].[Services].[Consulting]
    }
   ,{[Month.Year].[2015].[03]}
  );
```

the result is this:

```
                   Measures
Department   CumulativeSales
All
```

The CumulativeSales shows no value. There are still no sales in March 2015, but it should show January+February sales.
Thanks in advance for the help